# Why are the array elements not being modified inside the `filter` method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I’m trying to understand the `filter` method. I found a script example and modified it to multiply all elements of the original array by two:

```js
function zeroFill() {
  let list = [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0]
  
  console.log(list)
  
  const multiplyByTwo = (ar) => ar.filter((word, index, arr) => {
    arr[index + 1] *= 2
    
    return true
  })
  
  console.log(multiplyByTwo(list))
}
```

All but the first element of the array get modified. If I change the `arr[index + 1]` to `arr[index]`, none of the elements get modified. I am trying to understand how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.filter()`, as the name states, filters the array and returns a **new** array containing the items that pass the filter.

What you need is `Array.map()` if you want a mapped (and also new) array. Otherwise you can use `Array.forEach()`

```js
// In this function, a new array is created and returned, with modified items
function zeroFillWithMap() {
  let list = [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0]
  const multiplyByTwo = list.map(i => i*2)
  console.log('Mapped New Array', multiplyByTwo)
}

zeroFillWithMap();


// In this function, a new array is NOT created and the items of the original array are modified
function zeroFillWithForEach() {
  let list = [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0]
  
  list.forEach((item, index, originalArray) => originalArray[index] *= 2)
  console.log('Modified Original Array', list)
}

zeroFillWithForEach();
```

Answer (score 3):

As you already know `map` is the correct way to achieve the mentioned requirement let me try to explain why the `filter` is not working.

You must understand the [return value of the filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#return_value) which is a new array **with the elements that pass the test**.

```
function zeroFill() {
  let list = [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0];
  console.log("before = ", list);
  const multiplyByTwo = (ar) =>
    ar.filter((word, index, arr) => {
      arr[index] *= 2;   // <--- Manipulating the current list
      return true;     // <----- Return the current element: word
    });
  console.log("after = ", multiplyByTwo(list));
}

zeroFill();
```

In the case of `arr[index] * 2`, you are multiplying each element by 2 (and modifying the `list` array too) but you are returning the current element that is represented by `word` in the above code.

Answer (score 2):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a *new array* with the array elements of `list` based on its return value.
The array values do get modified in both cases, i.e. when using `arr[index + 1] *= 2` and `arr[index] *= 2`.
However, the value that lands in the resulting array is the same value passed as `word`.

See the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.filter):

1. The array element at index *k* of array *O* is retrieved and stored as *kValue*.
2. The callback function is called with arguments (*kValue*, *k*, *O*).
3. If the callback function returns a truthy value, put *kValue* into the resulting array.

At no point is the array element at index *k* of array *O* retrieved *again*.

Your modification with `arr[index] *= 2` always comes too late; the value that is going to be added has already been retrieved from the array by the `filter` method.
Your modifications with `arr[index + 1] *= 2` will modify the next index, which is the value that `filter` retrieves in the *next* iteration.
That’s why you see changed values starting from index `1`.
Index `0` didn’t see a modification yet, so `filter` receives the original value and adds it to the resulting array.

Log `list`, not only `multiplyByTwo(list)`, to see the changed values.

You are misusing `filter` here.
You should use `map` instead to change every value to a different value, or `forEach` if you want to mutate the array with something like `arr[index + 1] *= 2`.

To multiply every element by two:

```js
console.log(list.map((value) => value * 2));
```

Comment: this helps a lot. I was mostly trying to understand the filter method behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` function is not designed for this purpose. It's designed to filter out the array elements you need.

For your specific case, I would use `.map` method, as it will modify the array as needed and is designed to walk arrays.

```
const multiplyByTwo = (ar) => ar.map((current) => current * 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to modify an array with `.filter` which is not a good practice. You can use `.map` when you want to do something with the array items.

```js
function zeroFill() {
  let list = [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0]
  console.log(list)
  const multiplyByTwo = ( ar) => ar.map( (item, index, ) => {
    return item *= 2
    
  })
  console.log(multiplyByTwo(list))
}
zeroFill();
```

Answer (score 1):

First I will try to explain why you got this behavior, run this code and try to understand:

```
let list = [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0]

function zeroFill() {
  console.log('list before filter: ', list)
  const multiplyByTwo = ( ar) => ar.filter((word, index, arr) => {
    console.log(arr === list); //arr and list have the same reference
    arr[index] *= 2; //you will be modifing list[index], that is the current value being filtered, so you you will get the old value
    //arr[index + 1] *= 2; //you will modifying list[index + 1], so in the next loop the value will be the new one
    return true
  }); //The result of filter will create a new array
  
  console.log('multiplyByTwo result:', multiplyByTwo(list))
  console.log('list after filter: ', list);
}
```

You should use .filter just to pick the values you want based on a condition, not to modify an array while you are filtering it, you should use .map for this purpose:

```
const list = [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0];
const multiplyByTwo  = list.map((current) => current * 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you know about the "Map Method In JS". I think the problem you proposed could be solved much easily using that method. I am gonna leave my code here on how i solved your problem.

```js
const zeroFill = (list) => {
  console.log("orignal array: " + list);
  const multiplyByTwo = list.map((item) => {
    return item * 2;
  });
  console.log("multiplied by two array: " + multiplyByTwo);
};

zeroFill([1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0]);
```

but if you need your problem solved using only the filter method, I'd be happy to help in that situation too.

And yeah, if you want to know more about "Map Method In Javascript". I am gonna link few articles from MDN and W3SCHOOL.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map